# Is "approaches" used perfectly here?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> The soldier starts walking toward the mother and her child. The mother protectively steps in front of her child as the soldier approaches.

Is my use of "approaches" perfectly natural here?

Comment: Why do you think it is not?

Comment: "of her child" is unnecessary duplication - I would remove that, but the rest is fine, and even that is a minor style point, rather than specifically wrong.

Comment: If you want to avoid _approaches_ then _nears_ would also work but it is fine as it is.

Comment: More typical would be **the woman and her child** or **the child and her/his mother**. This is not a question of grammar, but of what a reader might expect.